# How read and write from a file without using the stdio.h library?

Tags: c, readfile

***Context:*** This is a question on a **study guide** for an exam.

> ***Question***: Write a piece of code that uses the low-level Unix I/O system calls (not stdio or iostreams) that does the following:
>
> > o Open a file named "data.txt" for reading.
> >
> > o Read up to 512 bytes from the file into an array named buf.
> >
> > o Close the file.
>
> If there was an error at any step, print an error message and exit the program. 
>   Include the definitions of any variables used by your code.

I am using the pico IDE in a linux environment in the `c` language. I know how to do this easily using `#include <stdio.h>` but I have no idea how I would write code without it. Right now I currently have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 // File var
 FILE *fileVar;
 char buff[512];

 // Open it
 fileVar = fopen("data.txt", "r");

 // Check for error
 if(fileVar == NULL)
 {
   perror("Error is: ");
 }
 else
 {
   fscanf(fileVar, "%s", buff);
   printf("The file contains:  %s\n", buff);
   fgets(buff, 512, (FILE*)fileVar);
   fclose(fileVar);
 }

}
```

How can I translate the above code to work without using the library `#include<stdio.h>` ?

Comment: Presumably it's something you learned about in class at one point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions you need are called `open()` (from `<fcntl.h>`), `read()` (from `<unistd.h>`)  and `close()` (from `<unistd.h>`). Here is a usage example:

```
fd = open("input_file", O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    /* error handling here */
}

count = read(fd, buf, 512);
if (count == -1) {
    /* error handling here */
}

close(fd);
```

Comment: No error handle for `close()`? Maybe you hurt `close()`'s feelings?

Comment: @chux I think in this case it's safe to ignore the error on `close()` as we are not writing into the file.

Comment: `close()` and `fclose()` [get no respect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodney_Dangerfield#Career_surge).  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The question says to use the UNIX low-level I/O routines.  Those are all defined in unistd.h, so you will need `#include <unistd.h>` and then will need to call `open`, `read`, and `close` defined therein.

Comment: This answer is very short. It should probably be a comment or expanded.